# why does my program take long to access files the first time

Tags: windows, file-management

So I have this program that goes through a bunch of mp3 files in a folder and reads some data off of them. When I run it, it takes a while. That seemed fair enough. But when I run it again after the first time, it doesn't take all that long. How can that be !?

I'm using a windows machine and the program is a python script.
If you want to have a look at the script [Here is the link](https://gist.github.com/madhaven/6219bb94408cc06f05bec605b8c0451b)

Comment: Likely OS caching of the data you read massively speeding up disk io.

Comment: What type of data drive(s) are you running in your computer?

Comment: Agree with davidgo - the files are most likely in the cache the second time you run the program.

Comment: i'm using an hdd... does hdd/ssd change the way this works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commentators have remarked: Operating systems and hard-disk subsystems perform [several types of Disk Caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_cache) to speed up re-reading a file that was recently read.

Your program is initially slow because it probably reads a large amount of data from a large number of largely-fragmented large-sized files scattered over a large area of the disk.